# Windows service receiving MSMQ message only first time when service starts

Tags: c#, windows-services, msmq

I am first time working with both windows service and MSMQ. I am trying to read  messages from queue. When I start my windows service, i am receiving only first message and next message not able to read, service is still running. if I restart the service It is reading first message from the queue. Please let me know how to fix this issue.

This is my code on start of my service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        MessageQueue msMq = null;
        JobModel j = new JobModel();
        msMq = new MessageQueue(queueRequestName);
        try
        {            
            if (msMq != null)
            {                    
                msMq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(JobModel) });
                var message = (JobModel)msMq.BeginReceive();        

            }
        }

        catch (MessageQueueException ee)
        {
            Console.Write(ee.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception eee)
        {
            Console.Write(eee.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            msMq.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think you shouldn't close the queue:

```
//keep your queue object in the service scope
//you might need more 
MessageQueue msMq = null;
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{   
    JobModel j = new JobModel();
    msMq = new MessageQueue(queueRequestName);
    try
    {            
        if (msMq != null)
        {                    
            msMq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(JobModel) });
            var message = (JobModel)msMq.BeginReceive(); 
        }
    }

    catch (MessageQueueException ee)
    {
        Console.Write(ee.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception eee)
    {
        Console.Write(eee.ToString());
    }
}

//close when you stop
protected override OnStop() //signature might be differnt
{
    msMq.Close();
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help

Comment: Hmm, you only do a `var message = (JobModel)msMq.BeginReceive();` once.... Is this code based on an sample of some sort?

Comment: Normally you fire-up the queue, i.e. starts it's own "listening" state and let that handle the message receiving part. As your code looks now, it seems logic that you only receive one message, the solution is not as trival as I thought

Comment: Yes, I didn't start yet on processing the message. How do I receive multiple messages? or How do I instantly receive message as soon as there is one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an event handler and attaching it to the ReceiveCompleted event, as shown in [MessageQueue.BeginReceive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.receivecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    MessageQueue msMq = null;
    JobModel j = new JobModel();
    msMq = new MessageQueue(queueRequestName);
    msMq.ReceiveCompleted += ReceiveCompletedEventHandler(MyMsMqEventHandler)
    try
    {            
        if (msMq != null)
        {                    
            msMq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(JobModel) });
            var message = (JobModel)msMq.BeginReceive();        

        }
    }

    catch (MessageQueueException ee)
    {
        Console.Write(ee.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception eee)
    {
        Console.Write(eee.ToString());
    }
}

public static void MyMsMqEventHandler(object src, ReceiveCompletedEventHandler handler)
{
     var msMq = (MessageQueue)src;
     var msg = msMq.EndReceive(handler.AsyncResult);
     Console.WriteLine((string)msMq.Body);
     msMq.BeginReceive();
}
```